# Latex, Fitting table using tabularx package to the textwidth in the paper

Tags: latex

I used the tabularx package to fit the table into my document. I checked the number of columns, but blank spaces are automatically generated.I want to expand the cells containing numeric text in columns 3-8 to the same width. Please help me.

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
  \caption{Comparison of average accuracies $\pm$ standard deviations (\%) achieved by the CRAGE model and Prior Models for the three labeling schemes on SEED and SEED-\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral4} datasets. The best results are highlighted in bold.}\label{table_1}
  \begin{footnotesize}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llcccccc}
     \toprule
        & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SEED} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SEED-\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral4}}  \\
        \cmidrule{3-8}
        & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{The number of labeled samples / The total number of samples (\%)}  \\
        \cmidrule{3-8}

         Scheme& Method & \multicolumn{3}{c}{---} & 851 / 1683 & 851 / 1673 & 832 / 1654 \\
        \midrule
        cross session\footnotemark & name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{---}  & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\


        cross session & name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{---}  & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        


        cross session & name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{---}  & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        
  

        cross session & name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{---}  & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\


        cross session & name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{---}  & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        
        \midrule      
    
        Scheme& Method & 180 / 10182 & 270 / 10182 & 360 / 10182 & 60 / 2505 & 80 / 2505 & 100 / 2505  \\
    \midrule
        random balance & name & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        random balance & name & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        random balance & name & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        random balance & name & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
        random balance & name & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\        
        random balance & name & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41 & 40.94 $\pm$ 8.41  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{footnotesize}
\end{table*}
\footnotetext{In the cross-session scheme, the samples in one session (Ses.) are fully labeled, and mixed with the totally unlabeled samples in another session for semi-supervised learning. The three experiments are performed on different settings of Ses. 1 (labeled) / (Ses. 1 + Ses. 2), Ses. 1 (labeled) / (Ses. 1 + Ses. 3), and Ses. 2 (labeled) / (Ses. 2 + Ses. 3) for only the SEED-IV dataset.}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odOu0.png)

I tried to scale the width for each cell, like

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l{0.11\textwidth}l{0.11\textwidth}c{0.13\textwidth}c{0.13\textwidth}c{0.13\textwidth}c{0.13\textwidth}c{0.13\textwidth}c{0.13\textwidth}}
```

But the problem still remain

Comment: You need at least one `X` column if you want to use a tabularx

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I fixed it thanks to your answer.

I apologize for it. I wasn't considerate enough when asking for help. I'll be more mindful next time.